# Javascript redirect - With Analytics

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to track how many users visit my site through one marketing channel. Customers are given a url, specificaly for that advert, that url then sends the user to the actual site. Whilst tracking them in the process. I'm not totally confident this will do it:

```
//Include jQuery
<script language="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">

 <script language="text/javascript">
 //Get IP address to block (ours)
 var clientip = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>";

 $(document).ready(function() {


 //If IP is forbidden
 if(clientip == "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
 {
      alert("Redirect has been disabled for you");


 } else {


 //GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

 (function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

 //Redirect User
 window.location = 'http://www.companysite.co.uk';

 }
 });

 </script>
```

This code is supposed to only run the analytics code if the user's IP doesn't match the forbidden one.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to load GA once per page. Once GA is loaded you can pass additional events/actions like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/item/to/track']);
```

Comment: hmm. how would this work? What can you track with '/item/to/track'??

Comment: Without the '/item/to/track', it reports the page's path. The above allows you send GA an additional page view that has the path set to something of your choosing. You could sent "/viewed/xxxxxAdName" to track ad views as well as your normal page views.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that should work, but if you're going to mix server-side and client-side code like that, why not just use the server-side code to output one bit of client-side code or the other in the first place. Something like

```
<!--Include jQuery-->
<script language="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">

<script language="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx') {
?>
    alert("Redirect has been disabled for you");
<?php
  } else {
?>
    //GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

    //Redirect User
    window.location = 'http://www.companysite.co.uk';
<?php 
 } 
?>

});
</script>
```

One other thing though..you should probably wrap that window.location in a setTimeout() of 500-1000ms to give the GA code a chance to execute before redirecting.

Comment: Your right, I tend not to mix server/clients side scripts like this if I can help it. But I think my way makes it easier to track whats going on in the page. Especially if it gets more complicated. And using javascript puts the strain on the client instead of my server.

Answer (score 0):

While this will work it would be easy for someone to get around the redirect as it's just written in JavaScript. You would be better off doing the redirect on the server.

Also, you don't need something this complicated to exclude IP's from tracking as you can just use an exclusion filter on the profile in GA. Go to the profile settings then add a filter with the following settings:

- Add new filter to profile
- Filter Name: Forbidden IP
- Predefined Filter
- Filter type: Exclude > traffic from the IP addresses > that are equal to

Then enter the IP you want to exclude.

Comment: Your right. Although this time theres no need to be secure in any way. It's just for statistical purposes. In fact, I think were going to just condition out the analytics code and do the redirect anyway.